# Reseting form fields, updating users id and blocking max number of users

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 questions about react. Firstly: How can I reset form fields using the button. Secondly: I'm deleting user by clicking on him with the button, but how can I change users ID to have it from 1 to 10? Thirdly: There have to be maximum 10 users. What should I do to block this ammount?

Code from React: jsfiddle.net/63mjaa3m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the changed [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/fn05ayhf/)

1. ```
   // reset form
   handleReset(e) {
       this.setState({
           name: null,
         email: null
       })
   }
   ```

then change input to contorlled mode

```
<input onChange={this.handleName} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
```

2. you can't. The user's id is generated in the server side, you need a new rest api to edit it.
3. add if condition in handleSubmit and handleAdd.

You code can not work without the server running. So I change the logic of data fetching. And data fetching should put in componentDidMount.

This is the code I changed:

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            response: false,
            add: "block",
            form: "none",
            name: null,
            email: null,
        };
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
        this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    getData() {
            new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            resolve([{
                id: 1,
              name: 'a',
              email: 'a@example.com'
            },{
                id: 2,
              name: 'b',
              email: 'b@example.com'
            },{
                id: 3,
              name: 'c',
              email: 'c@example.com'
            }])
          }, 500);
        })
        .then(data => this.setState({response:data}))
    }
    // fetch data in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount.
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    }

    handleDelete(e) {
        new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 500);
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.setState(preState => {
            const newResponse = preState.response.filter(user => `${user.id}` !== `${e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id}`)
            return {
                response: newResponse
            }
            })
        })
    }

    handleAdd(e) {
            // maximum 10 users
            if (this.state.response.length < 10) {
          this.setState({
            add: "none",
            form: "block"
            })
        }
    }

    handleName(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleEmail(e) {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value
        })
    }

    // reset form
    handleReset(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: null,
          email: null
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        const re = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
        // maximum 10 users
        if (this.state.response.length < 10 && this.state.name && this.state.name.length < 20 && re.test(this.state.name)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(resolve, 500);
            }).then(() => {
                this.setState(preState => {
                const response = preState.response
                response.push({
                    id: response[response.length - 1].id + 1,
                  name: `${preState.name}`,
                  email: `${preState.email}`
                })
              })
            })
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.response){
            return ( <div className="main"><div className="container">
                        <div className="adder">
                            <button className="add" onClick={this.handleAdd} style={{display: this.state.add}}><p>+</p> Add user</button>
                            <form id="form-reset" style={{display: this.state.form}}>
                                <input onChange={this.handleName} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
                                <input onChange={this.handleEmail} value={this.state.email} placeholder="E-mail..." type="text"/>
                                <input value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit"/>
                                <button onClick={this.handleReset}><u>Reset fields</u></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                       <table>
                           <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th className="first">LP</th>
                                    <th>USER</th>
                                    <th>E-MAIL</th>
                                    <th className="last"></th>
                                </tr>
                                {this.state.response.map((elem)=>{
                return          <tr key={elem.id} id={elem.id}>
                                    <td className="first"><div>{elem.id}</div></td>
                                    <td>{elem.name}</td>
                                    <td>{elem.email}</td>
                                    <td className="delete"><button onClick={this.handleDelete}>X</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                           </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div></div>
            )
        }else {
            return null
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Users />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) How can I reset form fields using the button?**

You have to use [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) to handle values. For example, for your name field:

```
<input onChange={this.handleNameChange} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
```

And the handling function:

```
handleNameChange(event) {
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}
```

And finally, to reset values, add this function to your component:

```
handleReset() {
  this.setState({ name: '', email: '' });
}
```

Since the value of your inputs are the values stored in your status, it will restart them when you click your reset button:

```
<button onClick={this.handleReset}><u>Reset fields</u></button>
```

By the way, in the constructor remember to bind your components functions to not lost the context:

```
this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
```

See [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more information.

**2) Secondly: I'm deleting user by clicking on him with the button, but how can I change users ID to have it from 1 to 10?**

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

**3) There have to be maximum 10 users. What should I do to block this ammount?**

A client-side way to do this:

```
{this.state.response.length <= 10 &&
  <div className="adder">
    <button className="add" onClick={this.handleAdd} style={{display: this.state.add}}><p>+</p> Add user</button>
    <form id="form-reset" style={{display: this.state.form}}>
      <input onChange={this.handleName} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
      <input onChange={this.handleEmail} placeholder="E-mail..." type="text"/>
      <input value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit"/>
      <button onClick={this.handleReset}><u>Reset fields</u></button>
    </form>
  </div>
}
```

That way your adding logic will be rendered only if there are <= 10 users.

Comment: 1) I tried it and it worked, but... it's better to reset values to null. 2) Nevermind, I made it by myself. 3) That's the perfect solution for me.